# Debugging two web apps on same port

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have two web apps.  When the user clicks a specific link in webapp1, it brings them over into webapp2. Previously, I had an instance of VS.NET 2010 open and running each web app.  This allowed me to step through code in webapp1 and then webapp2.  Webapp1 was localhost\webapp1 in IIS and webapp2 ran from the VS.NET development web server.

Now I have both apps in IIS.  Webapp1 is the Default Web Site in IIS.  Webapp2 is a child app under Default Web Site.  They look like this in the browser:

```
webapp1: localhost\webapp1
webapp2: localhost\webapp2
```

These probably need to be on different ports.  But I'm trying to avoid that since it is a different security setup.  In production, both apps will be referenced similar to the above and not on different ports.  Is there a way to continue debugging both of these on the same port?

-- EDIT1 --
The information above isn't completely correct.  Webapp1 isn't Default Web Site.  Instead, it is under Default Web Site.  Meaning webapp2 isn't a child of webapp1.  They are siblings.

```
Default Web Site
  webapp1
  webapp2
```

Making webapp2 a child app of webapp1 in IIS fixes the issue.  It now looks like:

```
Default Web Site
  webapp1
    webapp2
```

The above is the solution.  Sorry.

-- EDIT2 --

Spoke too soon, now I can only run one instance of VS.NET.  I get an error that a debugger is already attached when I try to start a second VS.NET instance.  Each web app is in its own solution.

Comment: Is IISExpress out of the question? You're fairly free to choose ports (of a particular range) and configure via the applicationHost.config file - I do a similar thing to yourself with WebApp A, Web Services B and C in 3 instances of VS (If necessary...) and can attach to any of them if I need to debug them (It's pretty horrific, legacy setup ;)) - localhost:10001 calls localhost:10002 and localhost:10003, etc, all in different iisexpress.exe's - I realise this doesn't answer your question, but it's *an* option.

Comment: If you're using IIS 6 or above, you could use the same AppPool I believe. If both sites are running within the same pool, the debugging *should* work across both sites from the same instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: @SpaceBison: Isn't using multiple IISExpress instances with each site on a different port, the same as using one IIS instance with each site on different ports?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: Both sites are using the same AppPool.

Comment: @4thSpace does that not offer seamless debugging between the two applications or have I missed the point of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different app pools? Typically when you debug via attach to process you attach to the process the app pool is running under (you can figure out which process id you need by going to visual studio admin prompt and typing appcmd list wp).

Comment: Same app pools.  I ended up consolidating into one solution and now it works fine.